# Initializing an empty array for a range of combinations in Julia

Tags: julia, combinations

I am trying to initialize an empty array for a range(3) such that each of the array is initialized 3 times. For example, in [1 2 3] each array has index of 12, 13, 23.
A python syntax for such task is,

```
a, b, c = [[] for count in range(3)]
```

However, I would like to know the correct syntax to execute this in Julia?

Comment: Is the 3 in range(3) hard-coded or is this a parameter?
It looks like hard-coded because you are splatting the outer list into 3 concrete variables in your Python code.
In this case, I would just explicitly define 3 empty arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Julian equivalent of your Python code would be:

```
a, b, c = (Int[] for count in 0:2)
```

Notes:

- using `()` instead of `[]` makes less memory allocations. You could still use `[]` though
- it is better to have typed `Vector`s so here I am creating empty `Vector`s of `Int`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and sharing the knowledge. Highly appreciated!